# XAML Indexer DataBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

I have got an `Indexer` property in a  class called `X`, suppose `X[Y]` gives me a another object of type `Z`:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding X[Y]}" ...???
```

How can I make a `DataBinding` happen inside the indexer? It works if I do `{Binding  [0]}`. But `{Binding X[Y]}` just takes the indexer parameter as a string which is `Y`.

**Update :**
`Converter` is an option, but I have plenty of ViewModel classes with indexer and doesn't have a similar collection, So I can't afford to make seperate converters for all those.  So I just wanted to know this is supported in WPF if yes, how to declare `Content=X[Y]` where `X` and `Y` are `DataContext` properties?

Answer (score 3):

The only way I've found to accomplish this is through a [MultiBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) and a [IMultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx).

```
<TextBlock DataContext="{Binding Source={x:Static vm:MainViewModel.Employees}">
    <TextBlock.Text>
       <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource conv:SelectEmployee}">
           <Binding />
           <Binding Path="SelectedEmployee" />
       </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

And your converter:

```
public class SelectEmployeeConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Debug.Assert(values.Length >= 2);

        // change this type assumption
        var array = values[0] as Array;
        var list = values[0] as IList;
        var enumerable = values[0] as IEnumerable;
        var index = Convert.ToInt32(values[1]);

        // and check bounds
        if (array != null && index >= 0 && index < array.GetLength(0))
            return array.GetValue(index);
        else if (list != null && index >= 0 && index < list.Count)
            return list[index];
        else if (enumerable != null && index >= 0)
        {
            int ii = 0;
            foreach (var item in enumerable)
            {
                if (ii++ == index) return item;
            }
        }

        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah thanks and this is the obvious solution if there is only one class. But I have plenty of ViewModel classes similar to this So I cant afford having seperate converters, Instead I change the Indexer logic to something else.

Comment: I've gone ahead and updated this to work across a multitude of collection types.